# Basic edit operation in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have used `CgridView` which list all the data from my table 'Jobs',also have an edit and delete for each row.Which has been implemeted using prebuilt template in yii.I tried few things,but it not working.My first aim is to display that particular row data in edit form.

My codes are as follows:

The model corresponding is,UpdateJob.php.

```
/*Model*/


 public function edit() {


        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', 'Admin', true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider('viewjob', array(
           // 'criteria' => $criteria,
                 'sort'=>array(
                 'defaultOrder'=>'key_skills ASC',
                 ),
        ));
}


/*Contoller*/


public function actionUpdateJob()
{ 


     if(isset($_GET['id']))     //Is it the right way //
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    }

     $model = new UpdateJob('edit'); 
     $params = array('model' => $model,'id' => $id
    );
    $this->render('update', $params);

}


/*VIEW*/ Have just tried to show the data as follows.

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Company Name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'posted_by'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'posted_by'); ?>

</div>
```

Thats it..

How to just display the row of a particular id. For the time being I don't want to update it. Please Help

Comment: Why don't use view option in gridview

Comment: In gridview I have used template like:  label'=>'edit',
                 'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("UpdateJob",array("id"=>$data["id"]))'

Comment: but I want that when user click edit ,new page with all the coresponding record of that particular id have to be displayed to edit.

Comment: Whatever you are doing till now is correct. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Parry..not been able to display the selected row in my update form.

Answer (score 0):

this will be done through js

$(gridID).yiiGridView('getSelection') should be your start

read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView